# QR reader crash when using asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, zxing

my application is closing when i try to scan a QR code. I was not using asynctask before and it was working alright, i guess i am having problem with the way asynctask works, any suggestions would be mostly welcome.
below is my logcat

```
03-26 12:19:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1104): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-101
03-26 12:19:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1104): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN pkg=com.google.zxing.client.android (has extras) }
03-26 12:19:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1104):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
03-26 12:19:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1104):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
03-26 12:19:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1104):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
03-26 12:19:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1104):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
03-26 12:19:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1104):     at com.example.restaurantapp.MainActivity$InitTask$1.run(MainActivity.java:68)
03-26 12:19:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1104):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnScan;
    TextView result1;
    ImageView imgScan;
    InitTask scan;
    //@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //btnScan=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        imgScan=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        imgScan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    scan=new InitTask();
                    scan.execute();
                }

            });

    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                result1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
              String values = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
              //String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
              result1.setText(values);
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Scan Result:" + values, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
           } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you cancelled scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
        }
     }

    private class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        protected Void doInBackground(Void...unused){

          new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {

                     Intent intent = new Intent(
                             "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                     intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
                     intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                     startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                 }
                }).start();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

please help, any idea what causing this?
thank you :)

Comment: You are calling intent for QR code in AsyncTask class. I thing you dont know the concept of AsyncTask class. You are calling intent for reading QR in background. so how it is goinh to work. Remove it from there then it will work fine. Refer following link for AsyncTask: [Link 1](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) [Link 2](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/) Hope now you can got your answer and can solve your issue. If yes then accept my answer and vote it.

Comment: first u are using `doInBackground` which already run in Background but u also using one more `Thread` for starting `zxing` Activity. sorry this will not work. suggestion: remove second thread from doInBackground. use `MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult` for starting Activity

Comment: i removed the second thread in doInBackground, where should i use the MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult?

Comment: i mean use `MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivityForResult` for starting Activity inside doInBackground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any background thread at all. Neither an Async Task Nor a Thread. Threads are meant for long running operations that might block UI Thread, Like running queries with database or http requests.

In your case you are launching a new activity for result so even if your log is giving you
"this application may be doing too much work on its main thread" then its a greater chance that the next activity you started is doing something on the Main UI Thread, not your mainactivity. 
Even if you are convinced to apply Async Task you are probably doing it in the wrong activity.This is because after launching the new Intent the current activity will go into onPause() and the main UI Thread will now be for the scanning activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void...unused){

          new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {

                     Intent intent = new Intent(
                             "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                     intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
                     intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                     startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                 }
                }).start();
             return null;
```

remove runnable thread for  `doInBackground`(itself is a thread )

```
 protected Void doInBackground(Void...unused){


                         Intent intent = new Intent(
                                 "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                         intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
                         intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                         startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                 return null;
```

This is what i caught on first look try implementing it and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

2 things need to do

1. Define activity in AndroidManifest.xml file

   ```
   <activity
           android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
           android:screenOrientation="landscape"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```
2. You must include zxing lib in your application or you must install
   zxing barcode application in device

As the lib you need to also create project as lib and then include lib in your project

**Note: Most important never ever do any process which has UI implementation in inBackground() method. This will only be for background process not for UI process.**

Comment: it was working fine when i didn't use asynctask, i already added the zxing lib in my project

Comment: but why did you start an activity in asyntask process it can't hold it in process

Comment: actually i was getting "this application may be doing too much work on its main thread", upon investigation, i found that using asyntask could solve this problem, but implementing it can be quite tough

Comment: like how it be? For that they are using there process handle so u need to debug about in that part and put this type of handle at there.

Answer (score 0):

In MainFest

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Try This